# Does string comparison == only work because strings are immutable?

Tags: c#, .net, string

I had a thought before when comparing two strings with their variables:

```
string str1 = "foofoo";
string strFoo = "foo";
string str2 = strFoo + strFoo;

// Even thought str1 and str2 reference 2 different
//objects the following assertion is true.

Debug.Assert(str1 == str2);
```

Is this purely because the .NET runtime recognises the string's value is the same and because strings are immutable makes the reference of `str2` equal to that of `str1`?

So when we do `str1 == str2` we are *actually* comparing references and **not the values**? I originally thought this was the product of syntactic sugar, but was I being incorrect?

Any inaccuracies with what I've written?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If we take a look at the jitted code, we'll see that `str2` is assembled using `String.Concat` and that it in fact is not the same reference as `str1`. We will also see that the comparison is done using `Equals`. In other words the assert passes as the strings contain the same characters.

This code

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string str1 = "foofoo";
    string strFoo = "foo";
    string str2 = strFoo + strFoo;
    Console.WriteLine(str1 == str2);
    Debugger.Break();
}
```

is jitted to (please scroll sideways to see comments)

```
C:\dev\sandbox\cs-console\Program.cs @ 22:
00340070 55              push    ebp
00340071 8bec            mov     ebp,esp
00340073 56              push    esi
00340074 8b3530206003    mov     esi,dword ptr ds:[3602030h] ("foofoo")  <-- Note address of "foofoo"

C:\dev\sandbox\cs-console\Program.cs @ 23:
0034007a 8b0d34206003    mov     ecx,dword ptr ds:[3602034h] ("foo")  <-- Note different address for "foo"

C:\dev\sandbox\cs-console\Program.cs @ 24:
00340080 8bd1            mov     edx,ecx
00340082 e81977fe6c      call    mscorlib_ni+0x2b77a0 (6d3277a0)     (System.String.Concat(System.String, System.String), mdToken: 0600035f)  <-- Call String.Concat to assemble str2
00340087 8bd0            mov     edx,eax
00340089 8bce            mov     ecx,esi
0034008b e870ebfd6c      call    mscorlib_ni+0x2aec00 (6d31ec00)     (System.String.Equals(System.String, System.String), mdToken: 060002d2)  <-- Compare using String.Equals
00340090 0fb6f0          movzx   esi,al
00340093 e83870f86c      call    mscorlib_ni+0x2570d0 (6d2c70d0) (System.Console.get_Out(), mdToken: 060008fd)
00340098 8bc8            mov     ecx,eax
0034009a 8bd6            mov     edx,esi
0034009c 8b01            mov     eax,dword ptr [ecx]
0034009e 8b4038          mov     eax,dword ptr [eax+38h]
003400a1 ff5010          call    dword ptr [eax+10h]

C:\dev\sandbox\cs-console\Program.cs @ 28:
003400a4 e87775596d      call    mscorlib_ni+0x867620 (6d8d7620) (System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break(), mdToken: 0600239a)

C:\dev\sandbox\cs-console\Program.cs @ 29:
>>> 003400a9 5e              pop     esi
003400aa 5d              pop     ebp
003400ab c3              ret
```

Answer (score 14):

The answer is in the C# Spec §7.10.7

> The string equality operators compare string values rather than string
>   references. When two separate string instances contain the exact same
>   sequence of characters, the values of the strings are equal, but the
>   references are different. As described in §7.10.6, the reference type
>   equality operators can be used to compare string references instead of
>   string values.

Comment: Not applicable as he compares the same string trice - interned as compile time constant.

Comment: @TomTom Applicable because conceptually that's what it does, though it will still hit the reference-equality shortcut before it gets as far as comparing the value.

Comment: Note that `string str2 = "foo" + "foo";` is not the same as `string strFoo = "foo"; string str2 = strFoo + strFoo;` The former case, the compiler will turn into a compile time "foofoo" constant. The latter case, the compiler generates instructions to call `String.Concat`. References will not be equal in the OP's code, so attribution to interning is misleading. (*Of course, different compilers and different builds may observe different results.*)

Comment: @TomTom: That doesn't appear to be the case. Please see my answer below for details.

Answer (score 10):

No.

== works because the String class overloads the == operator to be equivalent to the Equals method.

From Reflector:

```
[TargetedPatchingOptOut("Performance critical to inline across NGen image boundaries")]
public static bool operator ==(string a, string b)
{
    return Equals(a, b);
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Actually, `String.Equals` first checks if it is the same reference and if not compares the content.

Comment: @EricJ. But if they do have the same memory address it follows that the **must** have the same content (it's the *same* instance after all).

Comment: @Yuck - Only if interning is part of the spec, and not just an implementation detail.  Also, strings in separate App Domain's could be equal and have different addresses.

Comment: @psr Right, that's why the conditional check. If the reference is the same then you're done - that's it. Otherwise you'd have to compare the contents of each variable to determine logical equality.

Answer (score 2):

> Is this purely because the .NET runtime recognises the string's value is the same and because 
>   strings are immutable makes the reference of str2 equal to that of str1?

No. FIrst, it is because str1 and str2 ARE identical - they are the same string becauset he compiler can optimize that out. strFoo + strFoo is a compile time constant itendical to str1. As strings are INTERNED in classes they use the same string.

Second, string OVERRIDES tthe == method. CHeck the source code from the reference sources available on the internet for some time.

Comment: If you were to run the code snippet above and check `object.ReferenceEquals(str1, str2);`, you should get `false`. It's a distraction to mention interning when it's not applicable to the current scenario. Your second part is, of course, entirely valid.

Comment: `string` *overloads* the `==` operator.  You can't *override* an operator in C# because they're always `static`.

Answer (score 2):

The reference equality operator `==` can be overridden; and in the case of `System.String` it is overridden to use value-equality behavior.  For true reference-equality you can use the `Object.ReferenceEquals()` method, which cannot be overridden.

Answer (score 1):

In the order in which your code hits it...

`==` is overridden. This means that rather than `"abc" == "ab" + "c"` calling the default `==` for reference types (which compares references and not values) it calls into `string.Equals(a, b)`.

Now, this does the following:

1. If the two are indeed the same reference, return true.
2. If either are null, return false (we would have already returned true above if they were both null).
3. if the two are different length, return false;
4. Do an optimised cycle through one string, comparing it char-for-char with the rest (actually int-for-int as viewed as two blocks of ints in memory, which is one of the optimisations involved). If it reaches the end without a mismatch, then return true, otherwise return false.

In other words, it starts with something like:

```
public static bool ==(string x, string y)
{
  //step 1:
  if(ReferenceEquals(x, y))
    return true;
  //step 2:
  if(ReferenceEquals(x, null) || ReferenceEquals(y, null))
    return false;
  //step 3;
  int len = x.Length;
  if(len != y.Length)
    return false;
  //step 4:
  for(int i = 0; i != len; ++i)
    if(x[i] != y[i])
      return false;
  return true;
}
```

Except that step 4 is a pointer-based version with an unrolled loop that should hence ideally be faster. I won't show that because I want to talk about the overall logic.

There are significant short-cuts. The first is in step 1. Since equality is reflexive (identity entails equality, `a == a`) then we can return true in nanoseconds for even a string several MB in size, if compared with itself.

Step 2 isn't a short-cut, because its a condition that must be tested for, but note that because we'll have already have returned true for `(string)null == (string)null` we don't need another branch. So the order of calling is geared to a quick result.

Step 3 allows two things. It both short-cuts on strings of different length (always false) and means that one cannot accidentally shoot past the end of one of the strings being compared in step 4.

Note that this is not the case for other string comparisons, since e.g. `WEISSBIER` and `weißbier` are different lengths but the same word in different capitalisation, so case-insensitive comparison cannot use step 3. All equality comparisons can do step 1 and 2 as the rules used always hold, so you should use them in your own, only some can do step 3.

Hence, while you are wrong in suggesting that it is references rather than values that are compared, it is true that references are compared first as a very significant short-cut. Note also that interned strings (strings placed in the intern pool by compilation or by `string.Intern` called) will hence trigger this short-cut often. This would be the case in the code in your example, as the compiler will have used the same reference in each case.

If you know that a string was interned you can depend upon this (just do reference equality test), but even if you don't know for sure you can benefit from it (reference equality test will short-cut at least some of the time).

If you have a bunch of strings where you will want to test some of them against each other often, but you don't want to extend their lifetime in memory as much as interning does, then you could use an [XmlNameTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlnametable.aspx) or [LockFreeAtomizer](http://hackcraft.github.com/Ariadne/documentation/html/T_Ariadne_LockFreeAtomizer_1.htm) (soon to be renamed ThreadSafeAtomizer and the doc moved to http://hackcraft.github.com/Ariadne/documentation/html/T_Ariadne_ThreadSafeAtomizer_1.htm - should have been named for function rather than implementation details in the first place).

The former is used internally by `XmlTextReader` and hence by a lot of the rest of `System.Xml` and can be used by other code too. The latter I wrote because I wanted a similar idea, that was safe for concurrent calls, for different types, and where I could override the equality comparison.

In either case, if you put 50 different strings that are all "abc" into it, you'll get a single "abc" reference back allowing the others to be garbage collected. If you know this has happened you can depend upon `ReferenceEquals` alone, and if you're not sure, you'll still benefit from the short-cut when it is the case.

Answer (score 0):

According to the msdn (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/53k8ybth.aspx):

For predefined value types, the equality operator (==) returns true if the values of its operands are equal, false otherwise. For reference types other than string, == returns true if its two operands refer to the same object. For the string type, == compares the values of the strings.